# Why is my Python decorator sometimes of type 'str'?

Tags: python, type-conversion, python-decorators

**Background:**

I'm writing a decorator function, `val_limiter`, that limits the value of an argument passed by a child function. For the sake of thoroughness (and potential future use), I'd like to make my function able to accept numerical strings while being able to handle non-numerical strings appropriately. So, for example, look at the following code:

```
@val_limiter('5')
def test(val)
    return val
```

The return value of running `test(3)` is `3`. The function successfully translates `'5'` into `5`. The problem occurs when I try to do something like:

```
@val_limiter('foo')
def test(val)
    return val
```

This throws `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` on `@val_limiter('foo')`. I'd like to handle an exception for something like `test(3)`, where it would return an error message (i.e.: `'The argument must be a number (you tried 'foo')`

---

**The problem:**

When I run `type(val_limiter('5'))`, I get `function`, but when I run `type(val_limiter('foo'))`, I get `str`. Why is this happening? What's the best way to handle this exception?

---

**Source code:**

```
import operator
from functools import wraps

def val_limiter(val=0, limit=max, equal=True, force=False):

    val_types = [int, float, str]
    if type(val) not in val_types:
        val = int(val)
    if type(val) == str:
        try:
            val = int(val)
        except ValueError:
            return f'First argument must be a number (tried {val})'

    def decorator(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            ops = {
                "<": operator.lt,
                ">": operator.gt
            }
            for i in args:
                i = int(i)
                modifier = 0
                op = '<'
                try:
                    eq_string = 'is'
                    if not equal:
                        eq_string = 'cannot exceed'
                        modifier = 1 if limit == min else -1
                    if limit == min: op = '>'
                    if ops[op](val + modifier, i):
                        if force:
                            return val + modifier
                        raise ValueError
                except ValueError:
                    return f'The {limit.__name__}imum value accepted {eq_string} {val} (tried {i})'
            return fn(int(*args), **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

*edit: here's the full traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/playground/test.py", line 79, in test_bb_arg_1_is_str_fail
    @val_limiter('foo')
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

*edit: I'm currently running this through a test file. Here's a running excerpt of the failed test:

```
import unittest

class TestValLimiter(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_bb_arg_1_is_str_fail(self):
        @val_limiter('foo')
        def test(val):
            return val
        self.assertEqual(test(3), 'First argument must be a number (tried foo)')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Can you add the full traceback?

Comment: In case of a conversion problem the decorator returns an error message "First argument..." as string.

Comment: @Barmar:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/playground/test.py", line 79, in test_bb_arg_1_is_str_fail
    @val_limiter('foo')
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Can you add code for the method you have decorated?

Comment: @C.Nivs honestly, I'm just running it through a test file, so I'm decorating the above `test()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your try/except block in the outermost function of your decorator, you return a `str` when it expects a callable:

```py
def deco(a=1):
    # here
    if isinstance(a, int):
        pass
    else:
        # this string is returned instead of the function inner_deco
        return 'An error occurred!'
    def inner_deco(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    # this never happens
    return inner_deco
```

Your type-checking doesn't need to happen at the first level, do it in the `wrapper` function:

```py
def outer(a=1):
    def inner(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # Your error handling should happen here
            if isinstance(a, str):
                raise TypeError("I expected an int!")
            return a + f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return inner


@outer(a='2')
def error(b=1, c=2):
    return b + c


@outer(a=2)
def success(b=1, c=2):
    return b+c


error()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in wrapper
TypeError: I expected an int!


success()
5
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
if type(val) == str:
    try:
        val = int(val)
    except ValueError:
        return f'First argument must be a number (tried {val})'
```

When you pass `'foo'`, it's (correctly) detected as a `str`, and it tries to convert it to an `int`. But `'foo'` can't be parsed as an `int`, so it returns the error message.

Decorators are just syntactic sugar:

```
@val_limiter('foo')
def test(val)
    return val
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
def test(val)
    return val
test = val_limiter('foo')(test)
```

So for the `'foo'` case, that final equivalent line becomes:

```
test = 'First argument must be a number (tried foo)'(test)
```

which is trying to "call" a `str` as if it were a function.

The main takeaway from this is you shouldn't catch exceptions when you can't do anything useful with them. Many introductory programming courses teach *how* to catch exceptions, but not *when* to do so (in fact, the exercises that teach you how to do it often are doing it the wrong way, converting exceptions into `print`s or `return`s that make no sense unless the caller explicitly checks the types and values returned, which is what exceptions are supposed to *avoid*).

In this case, you might want a more useful error message, so catching it is fine *if* you raise a new exception with the nicer error message (you're making a friendlier message, but there was still an error you don't have the context to handle), instead of silently returning garbage (returning anything but a function here is returning garbage). So in this case, you might change:

```
return f'First argument must be a number (tried {val})'
```

to:

```
raise ValueError(f'First argument must be a number (tried {val!r})')
```

which raises an exception that can't accidentally be used as a function (the way a non-error return would be used).

Comment: I had initially tried raising my own errors, but the test file I wrote didn't like it, which made me think there was a better way to handle it. I'm new to Python and I'm just learning how to write test files (via a Udemy course). If you have any experience to answer this, is it better to ignore testing errors if the code works, or to continue refining code until it satisfies the parameters of the test? (I included the bit of test code for this exception as an edit in my original post.)

Comment: @gideonzane: Without knowing what the test is checking, I have no idea how to handle it. Returning a string is clearly wrong. It's possible you could have some default value that invalid arguments get replaced with; you'd never fail silently like that in production code, but in a toy? Do whatever gets you the grade.